# Java binarysearch algo on descendant list

Tags: java, list

In Java Collections.binarysearch() works for sorted list with ascending order. Is there an easy way to have a binarysearch for a list with descending order ?

Changing the list is not an option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an [overload of `binarySearch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that accepts a custom `Comparator`. Call that one, passing in a comparator that reverses the ordinary comparison outcomes.

For example, if you have a `List<Integer>`, then call:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch<Integer>(
             intList, Integer.valueOf(1), Collections.reverseOrder());
```

(Use of `Collections.reverseOrder() thanks to @MarkPeters.)

Comment: I thought about that approach initially, but I'm not 100% sure that it will work. Have you tested this?

Comment: [`Collections.reverseOrder()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder()) is really handy here.  You don't need to create the reverse `Comparator` yourself.

Comment: @Matt: Isn't a descending-order list the same as an ascending-order list with its reverse comparator?

Comment: @MarkPeters Never knew about that one. Way better!

Answer (score 3):

Use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Lists#reverse()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) to create a reversed *view* of the list, and pass the view into [`Collections#binarySearch()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29). The index in the original list is the list's length minus the value returned by `binarySearch()`.

Comment: Reverse a list usually cost O(N). Thus, reverse it to use binary search didn't seem a good strategy. The result will be some like O(n) + O(log N). In many scenario, it will be use worse than just scan all the items. I suggest you to create a custom comparator, avoiding reverse the list.